# Incorrect Manchester encoding from PIC microcontroller

Tags: microcontroller, pic, timer, programming, manchester-coding

I have written a C program for the PIC18F4620. My PIC works as an encoder, which encodes a data stream in Manchester code. My output is rd7, where it should appear the Manchester code, but only appears 0 to 1 transitions. Can anybody help me? Here is my code:

```
#define MAX_BITS 12
#define MANCHESTER_BIT 1



sbit ENCODER_OUT at RD7_bit;

sbit DATA_OUT at RD6_bit;

sbit LED1 at RD0_bit;
sbit LED2 at RD1_bit;

unsigned int Encode_val;
unsigned char Encode_State;

unsigned int Encode_Count;

const unsigned char START_SYNCH = 0;
const unsigned char SYNCH = 0;
const unsigned char END_SYNCH = 0;
const unsigned char SETUP = 0 ;
const unsigned char TRANSITION = 0  ;
const unsigned char COMPLETE = 0 ;
const unsigned char IDLE = 0;
void Start_Transmission(unsigned int ) ;


void InitTimer0(){
  T0CON         = 0x88;
  TMR0H         = 0xFE;
  TMR0L         = 0x0C;
  GIE_bit         = 1;
  TMR0IE_bit         = 1;
  TMR0IF_bit = 0;
}

void InitTimer1()
{
  T1CON  = 0x01;
  TMR1IF_bit     = 0;
  TMR1H  = 0xFF;
  TMR1L  = 0x06;
  TMR1IE_bit     = 1;
  INTCON     = 0xC0;
}

void Interrupt(){

  if (TMR1IF_bit)
  {
      TMR1IF_bit = 0;
      TMR1H  = 0xFF;
      TMR1L  = 0x06;
      DATA_OUT = ~DATA_OUT;

  }


  if (TMR0IF_bit){
    TMR0IF_bit = 0;
    TMR0H      = 0xFE;    //5 Khz interrupts   0.2 ms  
    TMR0L      = 0x0C;
    LED2 = ~LED2;


 switch(Encode_State){

        case START_SYNCH:
            ENCODER_OUT ^= MANCHESTER_BIT; //bring line low, start synch pulse
            Encode_State = SYNCH;
            break;
        case SYNCH:
            Encode_State = END_SYNCH; // synch pulse needs to be twice the interrupt rate
            break;
        case END_SYNCH:
            ENCODER_OUT |= MANCHESTER_BIT; //bring the line high, end synch pulse
            Encode_Count =0;
            Encode_State = SETUP;
            break;
        case SETUP:
            if((Encode_val & 0x01))
                ENCODER_OUT = ((Encode_val & 0x01) | (ENCODER_OUT & MANCHESTER_BIT)); //next bit to transmit "1"
            else
                ENCODER_OUT = ((Encode_val & 0x01) & (ENCODER_OUT & MANCHESTER_BIT)); //next bit to transmit "0"
            Encode_State = TRANSITION;
            break;
        case TRANSITION:
            ENCODER_OUT = (Encode_val & 0x01) ^ MANCHESTER_BIT; //set the line for transition
            if(Encode_Count++ < MAX_BITS){
                Encode_val = (Encode_val >> 1);
                Encode_State = SETUP;
            }
            else
                Encode_State = COMPLETE;
            break;
        case COMPLETE:
            ENCODER_OUT |= MANCHESTER_BIT; //transition done, bring the line high
            Encode_state = IDLE;
        case IDLE:
        default:
            break;
 }
 }
}




void Start_Transmission(unsigned int val)
{
   int i, parity_bit_count =0;

    for(i=0; i < MAX_BITS; i++)
        if(((val >> i) & 0x0001) == 1)
            parity_bit_count++;

    if((parity_bit_count & 0x0001) == 1)
        val |= 0x8000;

    Encode_val = val;
    Encode_State = START_SYNCH;
}


void main() {
  TRISD = 0;         
  PORTD = 0;
  LED1 = 1;

  Start_Transmission(0);
  InitTimer0();
  InitTimer1();
}
```

Comment: It would be best if you were clearer about exactly what output signal is being produced vs. the one expected.  Consider porting the core of your algorithm into a program which you can build for a PC and run to print output on the terminal and see if it does what you expect.  If not, it will likely be easier to debug there.

Answer (score 2):

You need to recheck your logic operations.
Your code:

```
if((Encode_val & 0x01))
  ENCODER_OUT = ((Encode_val & 0x01) | (ENCODER_OUT & MANCHESTER_BIT)); //next bit to transmit "1"
else
  ENCODER_OUT = ((Encode_val & 0x01) & (ENCODER_OUT & MANCHESTER_BIT)); //next bit to transmit "0"
```

will evaluate to:

```
if(Encode_val & 0x01)
  ENCODER_OUT = 1;
else
  ENCODER_OUT = 0;
```

because, if `(Encode_val & 0x01)` is true,
then `ENCODER_OUT = ((Encode_val & 0x01) | (ENCODER_OUT & MANCHESTER_BIT))`
becomes `ENCODER_OUT = (1 | (ENCODER_OUT & MANCHESTER_BIT))`
and (1 | anything) == 1
similarly, if `(Encode_val & 0x01)` is false,
then `ENCODER_OUT = ((Encode_val & 0x01) & (ENCODER_OUT & MANCHESTER_BIT))`
becomes `(0 & (ENCODER_OUT & MANCHESTER_BIT))`
and (0 & anything) == 0

You're also using an xor function in `ENCODER_OUT ^= MANCHESTER_BIT` and expecting the result to always be 0, but it will actually depend on the previous value of ENCODER_OUT.
I would rather do something like `ENCODER_OUT = !MANCHESTER_BIT` there.